# Self signed certificate in Android application of RAD

Tags: android, rest, delphi, ssl, android-manifest

I have REST service over SSL with self-signed certificate. I can call it from regular delphi application through TRESTClient. But When I use it inside Android application it raises the following exception during call.

> Exception class EJNIException with message
>   'java.security.cert.CertificateException:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found.

I found, that network security must be configured via adding `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` into `application` section of **AndroidManifest.template.xml** file.

```
<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:persistent="%persistent%" 
    android:restoreAnyVersion="%restoreAnyVersion%" 
    android:label="%label%" 
    android:debuggable="%debuggable%" 
    android:largeHeap="%largeHeap%"
    android:icon="%icon%"
    android:theme="%theme%"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="%hardwareAccelerated%"
    android:resizeableActivity="false">
```

Then I had to create **res\xml\network_security_config.xml** file with the similar contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/my_ca"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config> </network-security-config>
```

But where to place **network_security_config.xml** file. When I placed it in **res** folder inside **Debug** it was deleted during build. So it can not be found and app raises exception during packaging stage.

> Error: E2312
>   C:\Users\User\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\Andr\Android\Debug\TabbedApplication\AndroidManifest.xml:19:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'networkSecurityConfig' with value '@xml/network_security_config').

I don't know, where to place it and give RAD Studio know, that it must grab this file on compile time.

Comment: 'When I placed it in __res__ folder inside Debug' - but you placed it in __res/xml__, yes?

Comment: Yes. I created xml folder inside of res folder. In my case it is 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\Andr\Android\Debug\TabbedApplication\res'

Comment: When I add network_security_config.xml file into project via 'Project>AddTo Project...', Rad Studio creates it inside of 'assets\internal' folder. But it must be inside of 'res\xml' in order to be found during Packaging Stage.

I also tried to add this file as resource 'Project>Resources and Images...'. Result was the same.

Comment: Try Project -> Deployment. There you can specify which local file (outside build folders) you need to deploy and where. You cannot put files directly into Debug/Release build folders because they are deleted on every build by design (as you have already noticed)

Comment: YES. It works. I added this local file into Debug and Release sections. And it works. Thank you Dalija. You are my survivor

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly use Debug and Release folders to specify files you need to deploy with your application as they are temporary folders cleared on each rebuild.

For deployment you should use `Project -> Deployment` dialog.

There you can specify which local files (placed outside build folders) you want to deploy, in which configuration (Debug, Release or both) and their destination path.

Comment: Yes. I added into Debug and Release sections of Project->Deployment. Not into folders. Thank you.